# get distinct values from file via python

Tags: python, file, distinct

everyone!
I have one file containing one column with only numbers (Paramkey.txt) and i need to read the file and get distinct values and write them in another .txt file. Can someone help with the code? So far the code looks like this

```
infile=open("Paramkey.txt", "r") 
outfile=open("distkey.txt", "w") 
for line in infile: 
outfile.write(set(infile) 
else: 
pass 
infile.close() 
outfile.close()
```

And i get Syntax error, something with the else statement.

Comment: Show us what you tried. Distinct values -> use set. It should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Welcome to SO denbdar! As per h4z3, can you provide a reproducible example? You may want to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for information on what a reproducible example is.

Comment: so fsr my code looks like:
infile=open("Paramkey.txt", "r")
outfile=open("distkey.txt", "w")
for line in infile:
outfile.write(set(infile)
else:
pass
infile.close()
outfile.close()

But when i run the program it gives me SyntaxError: invalid syntax at line 5, the else statement

Comment: Please edit the question to include the code, instead of adding a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  So i managed to finish the program and it's working:

    infile=open("Paramkey.txt", "r") 
    outfile=open("distkey.txt", "w")
    for line in infile:
    output=set(line.strip() for line in infile)
    print >> outfile, "distincts:", output 
    infile.close()
    outfile.close() 

and i just want to add i used the "print >>" instead of "print()" statement, because my python is version 2.7.x not 3.x
```